# How to properly pass Json data to fusioncharts? -Multisiries-

Tags: json, angularjs, fusioncharts

First time poster, thanks for the attention.
Using web api to generate object to be consumed by fusioncharts (Multiseries). Object is produced as array of 2 classes (ChartCategories and ChartSeries) output seems fine and is retrieved in angular controller as data. yet after building up $scope.categories and $scope.dataset using data, I am unable to generate the chart with error 'No data to display'.

Partial Html template for chart:

```
<div id = "Div1">
<fusioncharts 
width="400" 
height="200"
type="mscolumn2d"
chart="{{attrs}}"
categories="{{categories}}"
dataset="{{dataset}}"
></fusioncharts>
</div>
```

data retrieved from web api: (copied + pasted)

```
[
[
    {
        "category": [
            {
                "label": "7/18/2014 9:30:01 AM"
            },
            {
                "label": "7/18/2014 9:40:00 AM"
            },
            {
                "label": "7/18/2014 9:50:00 AM"
            }
        ]
    },
    null,
    null
],
[
    null,
    {
        "seriesname": "Free_Memory",
        "renderas": "Line",
        "data": [
            {
                "value": "6632"
            },
            {
                "value": "5136"
            },
            {
                "value": "6376"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "seriesname": "Page_Life_Exp",
        "renderas": "Line",
        "data": [
            {
                "value": "48859"
            },
            {
                "value": "49458"
            },
            {
                "value": "50057"
            }
        ]
    }
]
]
```

and in angular, I set the $scope.categories and $scope.dataset like so:  $scope.attr is hard coded for the time being.

```
$scope.categories = data[0][0];
$scope.dataset = data[1][1];
```

What is needed in order to generate the graph?

Comment: looks like it should be `datasource` instead of `dataset `

Comment: tried that, no luck.  the sample for angular given [link](http://fusioncharts.github.io/angular-fusioncharts/#/demos/ex9) specifies it as dataset...

Answer (score 2):

Refer to http://jsfiddle.net/ayanonly1/yh1cvjqw/

I think following changes will make the chart live.

```
$scope.categories = [data[0][0]];
$scope.dataset = data[1].slice(1);
```